# Fullcalendar: while fetching JSON data how to change event color separately for a particular event

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I have this in my index.php

```
<script>

  $(document).ready(function() {
   var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    editable:true,
    header:{
     left:'prev,next today',
     center:'title',
     right:'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    events:'load.php',
    events: [
    { // this object will be "parsed" into an Event Object
      title: 'Today', // a property!
      className: 'booked'  // a property! ** see important note below about 'end' **
    }
   ]
    eventRender: function(event, element) {
        if (event.className == 'booked') {
            element.css({
                'background-color': '#333333',
                'border-color': '#333333'
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

and in load.php

```
<?php

//load.php

$connect = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=calendar_testing', 'root', '');

$data = array();

$query = "SELECT * FROM events ORDER BY id";

$statement = $connect->prepare($query);

$statement->execute();

$result = $statement->fetchAll();

foreach($result as $row)
{
 $data[] = array(
  'id'   => $row["id"],
  'title'   => $row["title"],
  'start'   => $row["start_event"],
  'end'   => $row["end_event"]
 );
}
// echo $data[1];

echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

I want to change it like this:

- if the title contains 'Today' then it should take className: booked
- if the title contains 'Tom' then it should take className: bbked
- if the title contains 'Tues' then it should take className: bked

How can I fetch the data and make this how I want?

Comment: Why is the code provided not working? Seems fine to me. What have you tried to do to make it work?

Comment: On a second look, you clearly have a problem in the JS section. You declared the property `events` twice. Please review it.

Comment: then what i should do? Please share your codes

Comment: What you're describing would be far better implemented in the PHP, probably using a switch statement

Comment: @Babai to start, you should read the documentation of the fullCalendar library carefully. Declaring the "events" property twice is an error.

Comment: I dont understand the docs i am amateur in javascript that's why i am asking for the codes to understand how javascript works i can do it via php but javascript i dont get that. If you have codes to share then you can share

Comment: Do anyone can think that the event color can change only by the title not including start or end? Because when my code is like this title:'Today Morning',
          start: '2019-10-21',
          color: '#257e4a',
          textColor: 'black'
          it works fine for me but i want  only title to work in my code not the start. So does anyone can help me to resolve it??

Comment: Yes Ricardo Pieper i sorted out that, please help me with my above comment, now i am facing that problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would make more sense to do this change in the PHP rather than the JavaScript, so that the events arrive ready-made into the calendar - it will be more efficient. Something like this would work:

```
foreach($result as $row)
{
 $className = "";
 if (strpos($row["title"], "Today") !== false)
     $className = "booked";
 else if strpos($row["title"], "Tom") !== false)
     $className = "bbked";
 else if strpos($row["title"], "Tues") !== false)
     $className = "bked";
 }

 $data[] = array(
  'id'   => $row["id"],
  'title'   => $row["title"],
  'start'   => $row["start_event"],
  'end'   => $row["end_event"],
  'className' => $className
 );
}
```

See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php for details of the PHP function I used to find the requested substrings within your title.

Then in your CSS you can define the classes something like this (of course you can change the exact colours to suit your preference):

```
.booked
{
  background-color: #57C764;
}

.bbked
{
  background-color: #D0BEE9;
}

.bked
{
  background-color: #C95E5E;
}
```

---

P.S. You also need to remove

```
events: [
{ // this object will be "parsed" into an Event Object
  title: 'Today', // a property!
  className: 'booked'  // a property! ** see important note below about 'end' **
}
]
```

from your JavaScript. You cannot specify the "events" property twice in the options. This is true of any object. If you have the same property twice (or more), the computer cannot tell them apart and will just use the last one you declare.

You can also remove the entire `eventRender` section, as that's unnecessary now as well.

Comment: i did what you have said now but it doesnot shows different color, it shows the same color for every event, i want different color for every events. I think you didnot get what do i want visit this link please https://i.stack.imgur.com/heesv.png

Comment: @babai The problem is that you didn't define your requirements properly. I see in the screenshots that your titles **contain** words like "today" and "tom", but that is not the **whole** title. That is not how you described it in your question. You said things like `if the title is "Today" then...` which makes it seem like "Today" is the whole title. Hopefully, if you understand the `switch` statement, you will know that each cases matches the **exact, whole value** of the variable, not just part of it. To find something **within** a string variable requires something different.

Comment: @Babai I have updated the answer using strpos() to find those words inside your titles. That should attach the correct class names to the JSON. I have updated your question too so it's properly clear. Next time, please ensure you state the precise requirement when you first write your question. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks!!!!! Do i ask you for more help, now the classname is taken in php but how to write the properties of that className???

Comment: @Babai I'm not quite sure what you mean? Is it still not fully working? ...Are you asking how to define those classes in CSS so that they cause the colour to change?

Comment: i have defined CSS properties of that class but it is not taking. So how can i do that...

Comment: @Babai Well I don't know exactly what you've done so far, since you didn't show me, but here's the general idea: http://jsfiddle.net/1egxtbqa/

Comment: Thank You! That was a great help for me actually i am new in coding with javascript dont have that much idea, but it was nice working with you. Finally i am able to dig into my problem! and also got the result

Comment: @Babai No worries, glad it helped. P.S. if the answer is useful to you, please remember to mark it as "accepted" (by clicking the tick mark next to it so it turns green). That way others will know easily that it solves the issue, and the question will be higher in online search results. Also, the person answering gets a small bonus when you do that...and that is visible in _your_ question history, so if you ask more questions in future, people will be encouraged to answer if they can see you give good feedback. Thanks and good luck :-)